# How to remove an element in array if it has particular characters?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to remove the elements from the array if it contains particular values.

```
var array = [hello@yahoo.com, www.hello.com, hello@gmail.com];
```

I want to remove the al elements which has @ signs. when I alert the array I need only www.hello.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid deleting/changing index of elements of array inside a loop. This is because the array is being re-indexed when you do a `.splice()`, which means you'll skip over an index when one is removed,

Instead you can filter out the element and get a new array which match your criteria

```
var array = [
'hello@yahoo.com',
'www.hello.com',
'hello@gmail.com'];
var newArray = array.filter(function(item){  
    return item.indexOf('@') ==-1
})
console.log(newArray)
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/0u60vp74/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
array.forEach(function(element, key) {
    if (element.indexOf('@') !== -1) {
        array.splice(key, 1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use a [Regular Expression](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp), along with another array, like so:

```js
var array = ['hello@yahoo.com', 'www.hello.com', 'hello@gmail.com'];
var array2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (!(/@/.test(array[i]))) {
    array2.push(array[i]);
  };
};
alert(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also loop the input array and push element that match into the output array

```js
var array = [
'hello@yahoo.com',
'www.hello.com',
'hello@gmail.com'];
var newArray = [];
array.forEach(x => { 
  if(x.indexOf('@') === -1) 
     newArray.push(x);
});
console.log(newArray)
```